What is the name of the movie with two scuba divers that are abandoned at sea?
Two scuba divers go out on a boat with other divers.  When the come back up the boat is gone.  The rest of the movie follows the two of them as they try to survive in the ocean all by themselves.

Welcome to [movies.se]. While this was pretty easy to answer due to the unique setting, in future please try to provide as much information as possible, like when you watched it, or anything else you remember and that might help the identification.

Yeah, I should have remembered that it was a man and a woman.  I saw it in the theater in the USA sometime between 1993 and 2012.

This sounds exactly like Open Water from 2003:

A couple on a holiday in the Caribbean decide to spend the day on a
  scuba diving trip. But was it the wrong decision? When a mis-count
  happens on the boat, Susan and Daniel are left behind in the middle of
  the ocean, the boat long gone. With all their hopes set on the boat
  coming back to rescue them, they try to keep themselves safe,
  especially when sharks start to appear.


This has to be it :)

That's it!  I could not have remembered the name to save my life.

Scariest movie I've ever seen. Seriously, I hate the open water.

@DustinDavis Yeah, me too. I think it's the feeling that you don't know what's below you. Different from the sky, where you always can see around you and make out the limits, including the ground.
